# File not found. Class memoir Warning: You are using the caption package with the memoir class

Tags: pdftex, warnings

When I try to run PDFLaTex, I get a warning, which tells me: "Class memoir Warning: You are using the caption package with the memoir class."
However, it does not generate me the pdf file. Any tips please?

```
% Document type
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt%,oldfontcommands
]{memoir}

\let\footruleskip\undefined %undefine footruleskip
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[belowskip=0pt,aboveskip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\syntaxonly
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Some colors to distinguish environments in the compiled example
\usepackage{parselines}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

%Inner and outter margins
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

%Citation
\epigraphfontsize{\small\itshape}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{8cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\begin{document}

%Margins
%\lipsum[1-4] %Dummy text genrator for the first four paragraphs

\chapter{Graph Theory}

\epigraphfontsize{\small\itshape}
\epigraph{"Begin at the beginning," the King said gravely, "and go on till you come to the end: then stop."}{--- \textup{Lewis Carroll}, Alice in Wonderland}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Well, you are explicitly telling LaTeX to check only the syntax. Put a percent sign in front of the command `\syntaxonly` (in the preamble).

Comment: Thank you!! And thank your for your help, it works!!! :) Why cant I vote your answer?

Comment: Btw why are you using fancyhdr with memoir, memoir has its own very well integrated system for handling headers and footers.

Comment: So, memoir is better than fancyhdr? Thanks for the tip and help!!

Comment: @user3641311 you can't vote for an answer because these are only comments. It is possible to vote comments though (but I don't know whether this is a privilege).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an output for your document, disable `\syntaxonly` by placing e.g. a comment sign in front of it.

The title of your post is misleading as it has nothing to do with the problem.

- `File not found`: There is no such error message when I run latex on your document.
- Warning regarding the `caption` package: Unless you have a good reason, don't load the `caption` package, it is already integrated into the `memoir` class. If you just want to reduce the space above and below the caption, use

  ```
  \abovecaptionskip=0pt
  \belowcaptionskip=0pt
  ```
- You don't need the `fancyhdr` package. Chapter 7 of the memoir docs explains how to set the headers.
- You probably also don't need `float` and `subfig`, since this functionality is also integrated into `memoir`.

I suggest to remove all packages except `ams*`. If you need some functionality, look into the memoir manual and/or ask here.

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thank you so much for your help!!! It has helped me a lot!!!